# replacing nth character using unix magic

Tags: unix, replace, awk

I have a blob of text like this:

abcd,def,geff,hij,klmn,nop,qrs,tuv,wxyz,....

Can you guys help me in replacing the 4th comma (,) with a newline using awk or any unix (mac) magic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change only the 4th comma:

```
sed 's/\(\([^,]*,\)\{3\}[^,]*\),/\1\n/'
```

(note: *rush* shows [a much cooler way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11576318/1258041)): `s/,/\n/4`

To change **every** 4th comma, add the `g` flag:

```
$ echo 'abcd,def,geff,hij,klmn,nop,qrs,tuv,wxyz,....' |\
> sed 's/\(\([^,]*,\)\{3\}[^,]*\),/\1\n/g'
abcd,def,geff,hij
klmn,nop,qrs,tuv
wxyz,....
```

Here's a `sed` [reference](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).

In a nutshell, the command finds the pattern

```
(( non-commas - comma ) (3 times) - (non-commas)) comma
```

and changes it to

```
"whatever is in outer brackets" + newline.
```

Comment: awesome! its working though its not showing new line. it just show "n" instead of new line

Comment: @PH. I guess it's a Mac issue. According to [this post](https://cafenate.wordpress.com/2010/12/05/newlines-in-sed-on-mac/), you could try something like `sed 's/\(\([^,]*,\)\{3\}[^,]*\),/\1'$'\n/g'` to work around it.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that I had gsed to replace this clumsy mac sed! Works Great!

Answer (score 3):

To replace 4th `,` occurance you can use:

```
echo "abcd,def,geff,hij,klmn,nop,qrs,tuv,wxyz,...." | sed 's/,/\n/4'
```

To replace every 4th occurance use:

```
echo "abcd,def,geff,hij,klmn,nop,qrs,tuv,wxyz,...." | sed 's/\(\([^,]*,\)\{3\}[^,]*\),/\1\n/g'
```

Comment: wow this is awesome short! its working though its not showing new line. it just show "n" instead of new line. is it cause I am using mac?

Comment: Damn, how many more cool `s` options do I not know? Where do you learn these?

Comment: @LevLevitsky http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html is the best `sed` tutor I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

It works because default action of `xargs` is `/bin/echo`
http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs

```
echo 'abcd,def,geff,hij,klmn,nop,qrs,tuv,wxyz,....' | xargs -d, -n4 | tr ' ' ','
```